# Do we need the tag "windows"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need to tag questions with [windows](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows)? Is there any reason to tag questions with that tag?

I can imagine users adding [linux](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux), [osx](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx), or [windows-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) and then describing something that is not specific to any operating system.
As the questions are all about Drupal, I think that using a tag for a specific operating system is not necessary, and it is enough to report in the question the operating system where the Drupal site is running (in the case it could be relevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering there are only three questions tagged [windows](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) I would tend to say "no".

Is it relevant to those three questions? Do you want this tag growing like a weed later?

Comment: I agree; it would be like using _php_ and _windows_ for a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I disagree. There are a lot of questions about Windows, in particular Drush on Windows. (This might have changed since 2011.) I have posted a new question about this - see http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3538