# Introduce tag for Drush on Windows or Drupal on Windows in general?

Tags: discussion

I think it would be very useful to be able to filter out questions related to Drush on Windows. A lot users struggle with this, and some of us has volunteered to answer these question. Now, my question is:

Should I create, i.e. start to use, a "drush-windows" (or "drush-win") tag or just "windows" in combination with "drush"? I prefer the later as tagging something with "drush, drush-windows" is redundant. In addition, there might be more general Drupal questions that are Windows specific - I guess. (Hm, I think my reputation is too low to create a new tag.)

PS! There is an [old question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/do-we-need-the-tag-windows) which is very similar, so maybe some of you would consider this a duplicate.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer "drush-windows" over the other suggestions but that's just me. Do you have links to questions that would benefit from this tag?

Comment: I guess many of the results from a search after "Windows Drush" would benefit: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=windows%20drush